# Access x.GetType() in let binding

Tags: f#

I have a let binding in a base class where I would want to know the runtime type being instantiated.

Is it possible from the let binding or will I have to go for a member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to provide a self identifier after the primary constructor.

```
type A() as this =
  let typ = this.GetType()
```